# jsp java variable access from vue component

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, vue.js

```
<vue-js-component my-prop-object="${javaArrayOfObjects}"></vue-js-component>
```

This is vue component inside .jsp file, I have access to javaArrayOfObjects but inside vue-component I can see only name of java objects, something like `[ html.java.JavaObjectsDto1, html.java.JavaObjectsDto2, html.java.JavaObjectsDto3, html.java.JavaObjectsDto4 ]`.
But if I console.log(javaArrayOfObjects[0].name) inside vue, that will print this name for me.

Please help how can I store whole objects in vue property. 
I tried `const x = JSON.parse(myPropObject)` but didnt work that.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your array of objects, probably an ArrayList<>, is calling the toString() method on the jsp page and putting a description of the objects in the memory in a string format in your Vue component. 
You need to convert the array in a JSON format first and pass this JSON object as an attribute to your jsp page, so your Vue component will understand the collection. One lib that comes to mind to convert the JAVA object in a JSON object in string format is [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson).
Check this [page](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-mapping-of-arrays-and-lists-of-objects) to learn how to do use the library.